# What is the phrase "suggesting ways to structure the competing considerations" modifying?

Tags: sentence-structure

> "In such cases, attending to the modes of moral reasoning that we characteristically accept can usefully expand the set of moral information from which we start, **suggesting ways to structure the competing considerations**."

> (source: Moral Reasoning By Henry S. Richardson)

What is the phrase "suggesting ways to structure the competing considerations" modifying?

- Is it modifying the set of moral information?
- Is it connected to the phrase we start? (i.g. we start from moral information suggesting ways to~)

Comment: If you attend to (deal with) blah blah blah, that activity will suggest ways to structure competing considerations. The second clause refers to the entire process involved in the first clause.

Comment: By *structure* they appear to mean *analyze*.

Comment: To clarify, it's a fancy way of saying, *Self-awareness of what you normally consider OK behaviour, adds one more thing to think about when looking at a new situation, and might help you balance what you see as the pros and cons of a new situation*. Or more pithily, *what normal people do in a new situation*.

Answer (score 0):

What Lambie said.  If you *attend to (some process)*, it will allow you to figure out how to *structure* (create a framework in which to analyze) competing moral considerations.

There are probably much less convoluted ways to say this, but philosophical writing is not normally known for *transparency*.